Excel VBA to filter multiple columns with one being a max date
I have tried finding a solution for this, but nothing I've found on any of the other threads seems to be working and I'm not sure why.
I have a table of items. A new row is created for each item when minor changes are made along with a timestamp.  The unique identifier for the item is a combination of columns 1, 2, and 3.  The changes can be made in columns 2-15 and column 16 has a time stamp that tells when the changes were made. So item 1 might have 5 rows because changes were made to columns 2-15 5 times. I need to be able to filter the table so it only shows the row with the most recent changes for any given item.  I have no problem filtering the table using the first three columns to select the correct item, but I can't seem to figure out how to filter for the max date for that item.  I tried converting the date to a number in column 17 but the max value is always zero whether I filter by column 16 or 17.  I'm sure it is something simple I am overlooking but I can't see it.
UPDATE: There may be a better solution for what I am trying to do and I am not set on using the VBA filter.  I have an input page where data is entered.  This is stored in several hidden tables.  Someone can edit previously entered data by selecting the item from a dropdown which is a concatenation  of the first three columns of the table in question above. When they hit a button, it pulls the appropriate data from the tables back into the input page for viewing or editing. The idea was to filter the table so there is only one row and then copy the results of that row back into the input table. The only reason I choose this method is because it works well for the other tables since there can be multiple rows in the other tables for one item. Upon further reflection, maybe a lookup function is the way to go for this table. Any other suggestions are appreciated. Even if I don't use the filter method, I am curious as to why my code isn't working for future reference so if anyone knows how to get it to work, I'd appreciate the help.

Dim wsoid As Worksheet
Dim wsinput As Worksheet
Dim filterrange As Range
Dim Copyrange As Range

Set wsoid = Worksheets("Objective IDS")
Set wsinput = Worksheets("Input")

'Clear any existing filters
On Error Resume Next ' in case there isn't any filters on it.  If no filters,  it might throw an error 1004

clearobjectiveIDfilter

'Find the last row in the objective ID table to make sure it contains something.
LastRow = wsoid.Range("B" & wsoid.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow < 3 Then
GoTo noobjectives
Else

'Apply Filter to compiled table based on values entered in the input worksheet 

'select letter
wsoid.Range("B2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("input").Range("D1").Value

'Select number
wsoid.Range("B2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Worksheets("input").Range("D2").Value

'Select id
wsoid.Range("B2").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Worksheets("input").Range("D3").Value

'apply filter for max date  - This is where the filter seems to fail.  maxvalue is always 0
Dim maxvalue As Double
Dim sorting As Range
sortrng = wsoid.Range("R:R")  ‘column 17
maxvalue = Application.WorksheetFunctions.Max(sortrng)    
wsoid.Range("B2").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=maxvalue, Operator:=xlAnd


Do you need to use VBA for this? It could be done with formulas (FILTER)

Must you filter the table in place? Or can you write the result of the selections to a different range?

I'll have to look more into formula filters to see if I can utilize that somehow.  I'm not familiar with them.  I could write the result to a different range , but not sure how I would search for what I am looking for unless you are thinking of using a lookup function.  I will update my question with more info of what I am trying to accomplish.   I'm sure there are plenty of ways to accomplish my ultimate goal.  Filtering just seemed like the simplest at the time I started this, but maybe there is a better approach.

Here is another approach using VBA:

Using a dictionary, store the latest item only for each "key" (combo of first three columns)

Then output that result to a different location:(Note that I used early binding for the dictionary object, but you can change that to late-binding if necessary)
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub FilterTable()
    Dim dD As Dictionary
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim sKey As String, I As Long, J As Long
    
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7")
    With wsSrc
        Set rSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=16)
    End With
    
vSrc = rSrc 'vba array will process much quicker

'collect most recent date into dictionary
Set dD = New Dictionary
    dD.CompareMode = TextCompare 'Case insensitive if appropriate

For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    sKey = Join(Array(vSrc(I, 1), vSrc(I, 2), vSrc(I, 3)), "|")
    If Not dD.Exists(sKey) Then
        dD.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=WorksheetFunction.Index(vSrc, I, 0)
    ElseIf CDate(vSrc(I, 16)) > CDate(dD(sKey)(16)) Then
        dD(sKey) = WorksheetFunction.Index(vSrc, I, 0)
    End If
Next I

'create output array
ReDim vRes(0 To dD.Count, 1 To 16)
 
'headers
For J = 1 To 16
    vRes(0, J) = vSrc(1, J)
Next J

'data
For I = 0 To dD.Count - 1
    For J = 1 To 16
       vRes(I + 1, J) = dD(dD.Keys(I))(J)
    Next J
Next I

'set destination worksheet and range
Set wsRes = wsSrc
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 20).Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))


'write results and format
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(2), .Columns(3)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Value = vRes
    .Style = "Output" 'may need to change or omit this for non-english language
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
        
End Sub


Data

Result

